Next.js Route Caching Issue After Token Expiration and Re-login Using Cookies
I'm using Next.js and storing JWT tokens in cookies for authentication. Every time a user navigates to a page, I have a Higher-Order Component (HoC) that checks if the token exists. If it doesn't exist or has expired, the user is redirected to the login page.
The problem occurs when the token expires. After clicking on a protected page, the HoC correctly redirects the user to the login page. However, after logging in again, when I try to go back to the same page, Next.js seems to cache the route and assumes that I'm still not authorized, continually redirecting me back to the login page.
Note: I am using the Next.js App Router.
This is what I tried to revalidate the path, but it didn't work
export const withAuth = <WrapComponentProps,>(
  WrappedComponent: FC<WrapComponentProps>,
  permissions?: UserRole[],
) => {
  return async function Component(props: WrapComponentProps & JSX.IntrinsicAttributes) {
    const authData = await authProviderServer.check();

    if ( !authData.authenticated ) {
      revalidatePath('/', 'layout');
      redirect(authData?.redirectTo || '/login');
    }

    revalidatePath('/', 'layout');
    revalidatePath('/', 'page');

    if ( permissions ) {
      //my logic for role validation

    }

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };
};

I've also already called router.refresh() when the login is successful.
